# loading a brands -> categories -> products hiearchy efficiently

Tags: c#, nhibernate, optimization, performance, hierarchy

I have a system which has 3 objects - `Brands`, `Categories` and `Products`. I am using Nhibernate as my ORM.

A product is assigned to one `brand`, and to multiple `Categories`.  For an ecommerce website we are building, we need to show the brands menu on the left.  For each brand, the idea is to show the categories which ONLY have a product, of that brand.

For example, if we have 3 categories - Camping, Hiking and Climbing, and 3 brands A,B,C.  If brand A has no products which are under the category 'Climbing', the category wouldn't show.

The problem is how to do this efficiently.  For each brand, it requires to go through each category, and check if there is at least one product under that category, of the current brand.  With 200 categories, and 20 brands, this would result in approximately 2000 database calls at the worst case.

The other option would be to load all products in memory, but if there are a lot of products (20,000 +), it would be slow also this way.

Any ideas / optimizations I could do, to make it load much faster?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [QueryOver](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover) to get, for each brand- its categories and the count of products in that category. something to the effect of (I currently don't have access to my references, so this may not be 100% accurate, but you'll be able to get my meaning):

```
QueryOver<Brand>()
   .JoinQueryOver(b => b.Categories)
   .Select(c => c.CategoryId) //or whatever else you want to select
    .SelectCount(c=> c.Products);
```

another option can be to define a formula [property](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property) for the Category class that would return the count of products associated with that Category.

Comment: A `Category` is not linked to a `Brand`. There is no direct link between `Brand` and `Categories`.  A brand will have ALL Categories which have at least one product of that brand.

Comment: in that case simply change `JoinQueryOver` to `InnerJoin` on products.